# Sliding Patio door mortise lock not able to take out

Tags: doors, patio, sliding-glass-door, mortise

I need to replace the mortise lock on my sliding patio door.
The process, which includes removing two screws and take out the existing lock, seems to be straight forward.
But I am not able to take out the mortise lock because it is stuck on both sides (left and right) inside the edge of the door trim. The door trim is made of vinyl and not easily bendable.
How do I take out this mortise lock? Cutting the vinyl trim may be an option but I am not sure how to cut it. (I have attached the pictures for better explanation of the problem)
[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]
[image: pic4]

Comment: It wiggles around like it's free? Have you tried removing the remaining screws? It looks like just the flathead screw may free the lock. With the lock out, maybe the other plate slides down or up to exit the end of its slot?

Comment: don't cut anything. Remove all the screws and seen what happens. If the plate doesn't immediately come loose, try lightly tapping a chisel or flat head screwdriver behind it. once it comes loose you should be able to turn it enough to pop it out of the channel. If not, look for a way to pull one or both pieces of trim off. But someone got it on there, and they probably didn't need to disassembly the door to do it, so you should be able to remove it  the same way.

Comment: Once you've removed the screws, try to give the hook a good tug.

Answer (score 0):

Unscrew the last 2 screws and slide the plate down or up in the channel to expose the mortise lock behind it. The lock should pop out.